# How to comeback to same view controller after logging in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

when I click my Wishlist page in my app then it will move to my Wishlist page there it checks guest or customer if it is guest I need to display login screen upto here working fine but after logging the screen needs to dismiss and need to move to previous My Wishlist page can anyone help me how to implement this ?

Comment: What issue you facing in developing this?

Comment: after logging it directly goes to next view view controller @dahiya_boy

Comment: I don't want it during when moving from Wishlist page to login page

Comment: why you are not simply present a login screen and manage dismissed with logged in data its very simple.

Comment: I am using navigation view controller in which after cart page it moves to login page and then to checkout page but where as my Wishlist page is on side menu view controller here I used SWRevealviewcontroller so is it possible with that ? @NitinGohel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should go with **@Nitin Gohel's** comment like below.

> why you are not simply present a login screen and manage dismissed with logged in data its very simple.

Just for your knowledge.
If you are using `UINavigationController` then you can go on particular screen by use `popToViewController` like below code.

```
for viewCon in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
    if viewCon is WishListViewController { // Here you need to change your class name instead of "WishListViewController"
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewCon, animated: true)
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: no I am using navigation view controller in which after cart page it moves to login page and then to checkout page but where as my Wishlist page is on side menu view controller here I used `SWRevealviewcontroller` so is it possible with that ?